# problem with drawing circle in android using OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to draw a circle in android using OpenGL on every mouse button click.

How can i do this?

Comment: How did you even connect a mouse to an android device?

Answer (score 2):

[Start with a triangle](http://www.khronos.org/img/books/openglr_es_20_programming_guide_sample.pdf). Then try to render a square. Move up to pentagon. Repeat until it looks like a circle.

For catching mouse events you would probably [start here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

Comment: plz give me some sample examples for this.

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_6624276_render-circle-opengl.html, second link from Google "render circle". Google will answer you if you pose it the right question